# Hardware Back Button on Xamarin.Forms WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I made a simple WebView App for my Website using Xamarin.Forms but when i press the back button it is closing the app, but i want it to redirect me to previous page (if any).

So here is my code so far:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Broswer.Source = "https://mywebsite.com/";
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">

    <WebView x:Name="Broswer" HeightRequest="1920" WidthRequest="1080"/>

</ContentPage>
```

So how can i change my code so can i get access to hardware back button?

Comment: You should have a look at the [OnBackButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms). When you want to prevent the back navigation to happen, just return `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could overwrite the `OnBackButtonPressed` method ,determine whether the webview has the previous page:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (Broswer.CanGoBack)
        {
            Broswer.GoBack();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```